# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined when I know it's there

Tags: reactjs

I have this in my `componentDidMount()`. I know the data is there because I have other data coming in that is successfully being displayed on the page.

```
Axios.get('/api/v1/recipes/recipe/' + this.state.recipeId, config)
    .then(res => {
        ...
        this.setState({
            recipe: res.data.recipe,
        });
        ...
    })
    .catch(err =>{
        ...
    });
```

In my return I have this:

```
{this.state.recipe.tools.map(tool => {
    return <ToolPill key={tool._id} name={tool.name} ... />
})}
```

I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

Am also doing some similar elsewhere and it works, furthermore this was working when I was passing in the recipe via state through react router, but now that I am making the call after going to the page it no longer works.

I also attached a picture:

**Edited to show state**
[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you console log `this.state.recipe` in your render method? Either the object is empty or the "tools" key is missing.

Comment: Sure, just edited post

Comment: Because you are asyncronously retrieving the data, `this.state.recipe.tools` is undefined when your component first renders. You should update the component so that it can correctly render without data, either by rendering a "loading" indicator or simply by returning null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add extra check for tools.

```
{this.state.recipe.tools && this.state.recipe.tools.map(tool => {
    return <ToolPill key={tool._id} name={tool.name} ... />
})}
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense, a little embarrassed that I didn't think of this before haha thank you